# how to insert php on html5

Tags: php, mysql, html

I wanted to insert php on html5

i trying copy code from  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="result"> </div> 

  <script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("do_dropdown.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

my do_dropdown.php  just select data from drop down list
[image]

but it doesn't show anything.
what do i miss?

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right thing to do, for my opinion
is to send your options data as JSON and to parse it with JS to required dropdown

for easy solution that will fit your situation, ill assume this is your PHP code:

```
//file name: do_dropdown.php
<?php
  $options = [1,2,3,4,5];
  echo '<select name="name">';
  foreach $options as $option{
     echo "<option value=$option>$option</option>";
  }
  echo '</select>';
?>
```

so you need to change your html file to PHP file (file.html -> file.php) and make sure you run on it PHP server (localhost as you are using right now)

```
<div id="result">
  <?php
    require_once "do_dropdown.php";
  ?>
</div>
```

there  are much better solutions for this, but I guess your'e new in business so good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try this ?
I think, It should not create any problem even if you're using HTML5. NOTE :: it should be .php extension file

```
    <html>
    <body>
            <?php
                    ....your code
                    ....from file <do_dropdown.php>
            ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

you can also create a function and call it from here.